# Joomla 3.3 get session variable

Tags: php, session, variables, joomla

in this url (URL SEF Active):
www.mysite.com/test/test-test?source=mycampaign

I want to pass the variable (mycampaign)on different pages.

With this code work fine in 2 page:

Page 1 (www.mysite.com/index.php/test/test-test?source=mycampaign):

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['source'] = $_GET['source'];
```

Page 2

```
session_start(); 
$source = $_SESSION['source'];
```

Page 3

```
session_start(); 
$source = $_SESSION['source'];
```

When I get to page 3 the variable does not work anymore. The url change this way: www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_users&view=registration&Itemid=371

this code works perfectly with URL SEF disabled and with url string "&source=mycampaign" instead of "?source=mycampaign"

Can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: If you want to pass variables through sef url then you need to change the router file of that component. if it doesnt parse the url correctly it wont work. Can you share your code so I could look at it.

Comment: I was able to solve with this code (in the index template page):

         session_start();
         if (isset($_GET["source"])) {
         $_SESSION["source"] = $_GET["source"];
    
   }

And in page3:

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["source"])){
 

}
session_destroy();

It's correct?

Comment: This code doesnt look safe. Be careful using $_GET. I am not a security expert but its better to have opinion from others. joomla has different way to handle sessions https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_access_session_variables_set_by_an_external_script

Answer (score 2):

You can use session instance in Joomla 3 for that.
Page 1:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('source',JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('source'));
```

Page 2 and 3:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$source = $session->get('source');
```